# Changing OnClick with Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, onclick

I want to be able to change the OnClick event when a other part of the page Javascript has been selected. So that the OnClick corresponds with that.

```
<a href="#" id="black" onClick="javascript:changetxt
  ('#333');">Black</a>
```

Can turn into:

```
<a href="#" id="black" onClick="javascript:changetxt
  ('#666');">Black</a>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Did it work? If not, why not? Also, where does PHP fit into all this?

Comment: I tried the element.setAttribute("onclick","code to run"); and works. But I have to use getElementById which is a problem because I want to select all IDs. I'd use class, but the setAttrirbute wont work that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change `onclick` just like any other attribute.

```
// Works, but not recommended:
element.setAttribute("onclick","code to run");

// Better:
element.onclick = function() {code to run};

// There are options with event handlers too, but they're needlessly complicated
```

Note that you do NOT need `javascript:` at the start of an event handler. The only reason you don't get an error is because it is parsed as a label called `javascript`, which is fine.

Comment: An expansion: `javascript:` is only used to specify the JavaScript protocol in a URI, e.g. `<a href='javascript:alert("icky")'>icks!</a>`).